# Snakemake: strip off path from input

Tags: snakemake

I want to write a pipeline in `snakemake` that takes an input file from `config.yaml`, runs a command, and writes the output to the current directory under the original filename + new suffix.

`Snakefile`

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
rule target:
    input:
        config["reads"]+".fasta.gz",

rule raw_convert:
    input:
        config["reads"]
    output:
        config["reads"]+".fasta.gz" # old path specified here
    shell:
        "sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' {input} | gzip > {output}"
```

`config.yaml`

```
reads: /path/to/dir/myreads.fq.gz
```

Using `bash`, I would write something like to get the file `myreads.fq.gz.fasta.gz`:

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' ${input} | gzip >$(basename ${input}).fasta.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I pair read basenames to their full path in a dict, and then use it in rules. This would fail if basenames are not unique though.

```
import os

d = {}
for read in config["reads"]:
    basename = os.path.basename(read)
    d[basename] = read

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{read_basename}.fasta.gz', read_basename=list(d.keys()))

rule xxx:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: d[wildcards.read_basename]
    output:
        "{read_basename}.fasta.gz"
    shell:
        'soemthing'
```

You may want to replace `.fq.gz` with `.fasta.gz` instead of appending them. For readability purposes.

Comment: I am getting an `MissingInputException`: `Missing input files for rule raw_convert:`

Comment: Can you post what you get in dictionary (`d` in my example code)?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Print it using `print d`

Comment: This is the output: `{'': '/', 'p': 'p', 'a': 'a', 't': 't', 'h': 'h', 'o': 'o', 'd': 'd', 'i': 'i', 'r': 'r', 'm': 'm', 'y': 'y', 'e': 'e', 's': 's', '.': '.', 'f': 'f', 'q': 'q', 'g': 'g', 'z': 'z'}`

Comment: Problem is in your config file. You need to use [lists](https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot%27s-introduction-to-yaml#lists) in yaml config instead of key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with some code that seems to do the trick:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"
import os
basenamereads = os.path.basename(config["reads"])

rule target:
    input: expand("{myoutput}.fasta.gz", myoutput=basenamereads)

rule xxx:
    input:
        config["reads"]
    output:
        os.path.basename(config["reads"])+".fasta.gz"
    shell:
        "cat {input} >{output}"
```